# how to save card details without making payment on stripe?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I want to save customer's card details and use them for future usage. I am asking the users to enter the card details, For that I am creating a customer on stripe, then creating a setup intent using `stripe.setupIntents.create()`. and I have created stripe elements using `stripe.elements()` Now I want to save the card, so which method or api is used to save the card-details on stripe?

I have gone throgh the docs but coul not find a proper way
Can anyody tell me what to do next?

Comment: I hope you are aware that *you* do not save any card details, that is stripe's job.

Comment: I don't think it is legal to save people's credit card numbers. You simply shouldn't!

Comment: I am saving the card details on stripe only. I am not storing them in my database

Comment: SetupIntents are the way to do this. After you have confirmed the Setup Intent, are you not seeing the new payment method on the Customer's page in the Stripe Dashboard?

Comment: Or is your question saying that you don't know what to do after creating the SetupIntent and initiating elements client side? In that case, you can follow this doc from this step. If you are already using this doc and are stuck on that step, can you tell us more about what you are stuck on? https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#web-submit-payment-details

Comment: I was having an error for incomaptibilty, so I used ```confirmCardSetup``` method and it works perfectly fine, It saves the card and also attches the card with the customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the method

```
           setupIntent.client_secret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: card,
                billing_details: {
                    name: "name"
                }
            }
```